# how to add a class into the existing classes based on a bool condition in angular 2

Tags: angular

How do you place the "active" class in an element based on a typeScript boolean condition?

My use case:

Instead of just the `class="collapsible-header "` like this

```
<div class="collapsible-header " >
My Title
</div>
```

I would like this to be written:

```
<div class="collapsible-header active" >
My Title
</div>
```

As you see there is also the "active" class in there. 
But this should appear only and only if myBool is true

How do we make this happen?

Comment: Try `class="collapsible-header" [ngClass]="{'active': myBool}"`.

Comment: Nice! I asked for one solution you guys gave me two that rock!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use:

```
[class.active]="someCondition"
```

> Class binding syntax resembles property binding. Instead of an element
>   property between brackets, start with the prefix class, optionally
>   followed by a dot (.) and the name of a CSS class: [class.class-name]

More info on the official docs: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding

Comment: BINGO! I had just completed my own solution but yours nails da heck out of it. Thank you. My implementation was `<div *ngIf="isEmpty(searchForm.language)" class="collapsible-header" >..</div>` AND `<div *ngIf=" ! isEmpty(searchForm.language)" class="collapsible-header ACTIVE" >..</div>`

Comment: could this be another alternative to the solution? `... <div class="collapsible-header {{ someCondition ? 'ACTIVE' : ''}}"`>...</div>

Comment: When there are multiple solutions to a problem, I try to follow the guidelines, but yeah yours works too I guess.

Answer (score 0):

A summary of *all* solutions to the original question:

solution 1)

```
<div class="collapsible-header" [class.ACTIVE]="myBool">...</div>
```

solution 2)

```
<div class="collapsible-header {{ myBool ? 'ACTIVE' : ''}}">...</div>
```

solution 3)

```
<div class="collapsible-header" [ngClass]="{'ACTIVE': myBool}">...</div>
```

solution 4)

```
<div *ngIf="myBool"    class="collapsible-header" >..</div> 
<div *ngIf=" ! myBool" class="collapsible-header ACTIVE" >..</div>
```

I think the solution 2 is the most straightforward one for my use case.